# Javascript create slug based on the name input, and display it on a disabled slug input

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, laravel-mix

So I have been trying to create a slug using Javascript, and allow my users to see what the slug will be, before even pressing submit. Here is my Javascript code:

```
function slugify(text) {
  return text
    .toString()                     // Cast to string
    .toLowerCase()                  // Convert the string to lowercase letters
    .normalize('NFD')       // The normalize() method returns the Unicode Normalization Form of a given string.
    .trim()                         // Remove whitespace from both sides of a string
    .replace(/\s+/g, '-')           // Replace spaces with -
    .replace(/[^\w\-]+/g, '')       // Remove all non-word chars
    .replace(/\-\-+/g, '-');        // Replace multiple - with single -
}

function listingslug(text) {
 document.getElementById("slug").value = slugify(text); 
}
```

Here is my html that I am using, which is using Bootstrap 4:

```
<form class="form">
      <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" onkeyup="listingslug(this)" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Example input placeholder">
  </div>
      <label for="slug">Your vanity URL</label>
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon3">{{ env('APP_URL') }}/listing/</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="slug" name="slug" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
</div>
  </form>
```

I'm getting an error that listingslug does not exist. I'm using Laravel mix to compile my code. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to use `listingslug(this.value)` on `onkeyup`.

Comment: Didn’t actually give me a change in it working.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change `onkeyup="listingslug(this)"` to `oninput="listingslug(this.value)"`

```js
function slugify(text) {
  return text
    .toString() // Cast to string
    .toLowerCase() // Convert the string to lowercase letters
    .normalize('NFD') // The normalize() method returns the Unicode Normalization Form of a given string.
    .trim() // Remove whitespace from both sides of a string
    .replace(/\s+/g, '-') // Replace spaces with -
    .replace(/[^\w\-]+/g, '') // Remove all non-word chars
    .replace(/\-\-+/g, '-'); // Replace multiple - with single -
}

function listingslug(text) {
  document.getElementById("slug").value = slugify(text);
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" oninput="listingslug(this.value)" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Example input placeholder">
  </div>
  <label for="slug">Your vanity URL</label>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon3">{{ env('APP_URL') }}/listing/</span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="slug" name="slug" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
  </div>
</form>
```